# who can create the users in Salesforce

Tags: user

who can create the Users in salesforce.

Are there any settigns needed to be changed the users of Salesforce to create other users or
only user with Admin profile able to create the new users?

Comment: FYI I have down-voted this post because the first several results when you google [salesforce create user permission](https://www.google.com/search?q=salesforce+create+user+permission&oq=salesforce+create+user+permission&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.6906j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) answer it, and your question does not demonstrate any research effort before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Knowledge Article 000005253:

> ## [What can Manage Users permission do?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005253&type=1)
>
> **Description**
>   If a subset of rights is needed to manage users but not manage Profiles or Sharing, check out the Delegate User Administration.
>
> **Resolution**
>   Manage Users allows you to do the following:
>
> Please Note: With as many different features available to customize within Salesforce and new features added with each release, it is difficult to list out every single action that "Manage Users" will enable a user to do. Discretion should be used when enabling a user to have the "Manage Users" permission, as this is typically intended for administrators needing access to make organizational changes.
>
> Profiles
>
> - Manage Profiles (more detail below)
> - Assign Profiles
> - View Field Accessibility
> - User Management​
>
> Sharing
>
> - Manage User Roles
> - Manage Forecast Roles
> - Assign Roles
> - Manage Public Groups
> - Manage ALL Personal Groups
> - Assign Public Groups
> - Manage Queues
> - Assign Queues
> - Manage Territories
> - Manage Sharing Settings
> - Recalc Sharing Rules
> - Manage Dimension Categories
> - Manage Sales Teams
> - Manage Account Teams
> - Manage Opportunity Teams
>
> User Management
>
> - **Create/Edit Internal User and have access to all User fields**
> - Manage Hierarchical User Fields
> - Assign License
> - Activate User
> - Expire All Passwords
> - Set Org Password Policies
> - Reset User Password
> - Reset Username
> - Reset Email
> - Assign Mobile Configuration
> - Assign Workflow Manager Field
> - Manage a User's Divisions
> - Manage a User's OAuth
> - Remove user sessions
> - View Login History
> - View Training History
> - Delegated Portal Administration
> - Create/Edit Portal User
> - Edit Self-Service User
> - Change the Account Name on Portal enabled contact records
> - Enable, Disable, View, Login as Community/Portal Users
>
> Other Permissions
>
> - Manage Opportunity Update Reminders
> - Activate Opportunity Update Reminders
> - Manage SAML Subject
> - Mass Emailing Users

See also: [View and Manage Users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_users.htm&type=5), which indicates that if you want to view user lists, you need to also have the **`View Setup and Configuration`** permission.